# Necessary and sufficient condition for a pure tensor to be zero

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, tensor-products

Let $A$ be a commutative ring. Then suppose that $M$ and $N$ are $A$-modules. Is it true that for $m\in M$ and $n\in N$, $m\otimes n=0\in M\otimes N$ if and only if $m=cm'$ such that $c\in Ann(n)$ or $n=bn'$ such that $b\in Ann(m)$? If it is true how can I start to look for a proof? It is false, where should I start to look for a counter example?

Comment: @BrianMoehring Yes, an element of $M\otimes N$ of the form $m\otimes n$ with $m\in M$ and $n\in N$.